# Coverting pseudocode of breadth first search to python

Tags: python, debugging

I am writing a Breadth first search to convert in to python. How do you convert the pseudocode from the bottom to the top in Python? Please Help.

```
def BFS(problem):

 node = node(problem.INITIAL)
 if problem.IS_GOAL(node, STATE: STATE):
     result = node
 frontier =  node.Queue():
 reached = {problem.INITIAL}
 while not IS_EMPTY(frontier) do 
  node = node.pop(frontier)
  for child in EXPAND(problem, node) do
    s = child.STATE
    if problem.IS_GOAL(s):
        result = child
    if s =! reached
        reached.append(s)
        frontier.(child)
        
return failure

def UCS(problem):
   return node || failure
return BFS(problem, PATH_COST)
```

[image: BreadthFirstSearch]

Comment: Please use 4-space indents so the structure of the Python is more visible

Comment: You don't put type hints in function calls, only function definitions.

Comment: The pseudo-code says `node.STATE`. Why did you split this into two arguments to `IS_GOAL()`?

Comment: The pseudo-code seems to have a bug. The BFS function only accepts one parameter, but UCS calls it with 2 arguments. What is `PATH-COST`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `node` as both a variable name and class name. Conventionally, class names begin with an uppercase letter, so it should be `node = Node(problem.INITIAL)`

Comment: You seem to be struggling with basic Python syntax. You're missing the `:` at the end of `if` and `while` statements. There's no `do` in Python. `=!` should be `!=`. You need to learn the basics before you can worry about more advanced algorithms.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - and test it on small example and compare it will calculations on paper.

Comment: @Derrick DesVignes - You'd have to state wherefrom the _pseudocode_ comes.